# How to store Indented python code in MySQL Database using Django ORM

Tags: python, django, orm

I am working on a python interpreter visualization where I need to save and execute python code, but the problem is that I am using Django TextField to save the python code but when I am querying the database I am  getting **Unformatted** , **Unindented** code

like:

Original code

```
a=3
for i in range(0,5):
    a+=i
print(a)
```

Code after retrieving from database

`a=3\012for i in range(0\0545):\012    a+=i\012print(a)`

I have tried to play with the string encoding but that doesn't worked too.
**Models.py (Code attribute only)**

```
code = models.TextField()
```

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to store Python files (or whatever source code it is) a a database. Why not use a files repository?

Comment: Yes I think you are right. I should make a file repository

Answer (score 0):

Python source code are (in general) encoded in UTF-8, so you need to read the source file using this encoding, for instance:

```py
import io


path = "path/to/module.py"
with io.open(path, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    content = f.read')
```

Then, you can store this content (a UNICODE string) in your `TextField`…

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But Actually I am getting this code as an AJAX request not a file repository

Comment: So, your problem come from your client (web browser). Are you using a `textaria`? Does your field support indentation? It may convert it to a single space of tab…